# Как указать ширину и высоту TextBox во всю ширину/высоту окна. WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

У меня есть TextBox в который я хочу выводить текст. Мне необходимо указать всё доступное пространство окна, я пытался различными методами указывать но так и не получилось адекватно указать, так же очень важный момент что я хочу использовать ViewBox. Тоесть должны быть некие стартовые значения, что бы окно изначально не сжимало, для это я устанавливаю  `MinWidth="1000"` и `MinHeight="500"`. Но когда я начинаю растягивать окно, поле не занимает то пространство которое стало доступно. Но при этом необходимо что бы текст достигая края поля переходил на новую строку, а не расширял текущее поле.

```
    <TabItem>
                    <TabItem.Header>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                            <TextBlock Text="Логи" FontSize="10"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </TabItem.Header>

                    <Viewbox VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" MinWidth="1000"></ColumnDefinition>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                                <RowDefinition Height="auto" MinHeight="500"></RowDefinition>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            
                            <TextBlock  Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"
                                        Text="Логи:"
                                        Margin="0,10"
                                        FontWeight="DemiBold"
                                        FontSize="20"/>

                                
                            <TextBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"
                                     TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                     ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" />
                
                        </Grid>
                    </Viewbox>
                </TabItem>
```

Answer (score 0):

Я делаю так:

```
<DockPanel>
    <TextBox DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" MinWidth="1000" MinHeight="500" TextWrapping="Wrap" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"/>
</DockPanel>
```